# Python bash pipe

Tags: python, bash, pipe

I want to pipe a python script's output to a bash script. What i did so far was i tried to use `os.popen()`, `sys.subprocess()`, and tried to give a pipe for an example

```
os.popen('echo "P 1 1 591336 4927369 1 321 " | v.in.ascii -zn out=abcx format=standard --overwrite')
```

but this didn't work, the values `"591336"` and `"4927369"` are the variables which comes as the output of the python script. but when I do this or change the values manually by repeating the echo command and the pipe, it works (in bash).

```
v.in.ascii -zn out=abcx format=standard --overwrite
```

the above part of the bash command is a part of Grass GIS

Can anyone help me!

Answer (score 6):

You can just use `print` to output to stdout and pipe the Python process to the next process, e.g.

```
python myprogram.py | ...
```

Where `myprogram.py` might look like:

```
for x in something:
    print dosomething(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
>>> stdin, stdout = os.popen2("echo %s | grep 'test'" % 'some test param')
>>> print stdout.read()
some test param

>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Python 2.6, the `subprocess` module is recommended instead of the deprecated `os.popen`. Here's an example:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(["v.in.ascii", "-zn", "out=abcx", "format=standard", "--overwrite"], stdin=PIPE)
p.stdin.write("P 1 1 591336 4927369 1 321\n")
p.stdin.close()
p.wait() # unless background execution preferred
```

Comment: this is the bash command i use to do the reading temporarily 
#!/bin/bash

d.mon x1
d.rast elevation.dem
d.vect abcx 
d.vect abcy 

#value=0;

while read line
do
#value=`expr $value + 1`;
echo $line
echo $line
echo "P 1 1
$line 
1 321 " | v.in.ascii -zn out=abcx format=standard --overwrite
d.redraw 
#sleep 1
done < "cordvals.txt"

this cordvals.txt is created from the variables which is written by the python script if i can change this it will be ok too (to put the python script's output as the input to this while loop)

Answer (score 0):

I really like John Paulett's answer.

I think your `echo` example would work if you used [`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system) instead of `os.popen`.

One way to use `popen` here is like this:

```
f = os.popen("v.in.ascii -zn out=abcx format=standard --overwrite", 'w')
f.write("P 1 1 591336 4927369 1 321\n")
f.close()
```

(You have to specify the pipe is for writing.)

Comment: As mentioned before, `os.system` has been deprecated since Python 2.6. The newer (and supported) `subprocess.call` or `subprocess.run` methods work fine.