# How bash script can receive output of python in pipe line

Tags: python, bash, input, pipe, output

I got two files:
myPython.py && myBash.sh

I would like to make myPython.py output an XML file, and myBash.sh receive this XML file as input then do sth on it.

What I want to do in console is like this

`myPython.py | myBash.sh`

The question is:
How to return an value in python file?
And how to receive an XML file for myBash.sh in a pipe line?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of Python bash pipe (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847195/python-bash-pipe?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

If you just do a simple 'print', it should work. For example:

`python -c 'print "foo"' | cat`

Comment: Thanks but no, I would like to publish this XML file to server

Comment: So replace 'cat' with myBash.sh that does that. What's the problem?

python myPython.py | myBash.sh, where myPython prints out the xml.

Comment: @user1853170, which part does the publishing? python or bash?